# No data by using RecylcerView and Retrofit2 latest

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I'm new to retrofit2 android. I'm trying to work around an app which displays earthquake information using retrofit and RecyclerView. But I'm unable to display any data fetch from the URL in JSON format.
Most of the times I'm getting No adapter attached; skipping layout error. I've searched a lot but didn't get it resolve.
I'm using HttpLoggingInterceptor to see response. Response body of my JSON data is showing in Verbose of Logcat but not in RecyclerView.
Sometimes no error nothing in verbose everything blank even app is blank no data.
Help me please with my issue.

URL from which I'm fetching data. I limit it to 2 so that you can see it clearly.
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&limit=2

This is my MainActivity.

```
public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Feature> featureList;
    private DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate() method called...");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_earthquke);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.earthquake_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
                .build();

        EarthquakeRequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(EarthquakeRequestInterface.class);
        Call<EarthquakeResponse> responseCall =requestInterface.getJSON("geojson");
        responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<EarthquakeResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EarthquakeResponse> call, Response<EarthquakeResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    EarthquakeResponse earthquakeResponse = response.body();
                    adapter = new DataAdapter(earthquakeResponse.getFeatures());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No data Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<EarthquakeResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}`
```

This is my adapter class.

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Feature> features;

    public DataAdapter(List<Feature> features1) {
        this.features = features1;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.earthquake_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.earthquakeMag.setText(features.get(i).getProperties().getMag().toString());
        viewHolder.earthquakePlace.setText(features.get(i).getProperties().getPlace());
        viewHolder.earthquakeUrl.setText(features.get(i).getProperties().getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return features.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView earthquakeMag,earthquakePlace,earthquakeUrl;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            earthquakeMag = view.findViewById(R.id.earthquake_mag);
            earthquakePlace = view.findViewById(R.id.earthquake_place);
            earthquakeUrl = view.findViewById(R.id.earthquake_url);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my API interface.

```
public interface EarthquakeRequestInterface {

    @GET ("fdsnws/event/1/query")
    Call<EarthquakeResponse> getJSON(@Query("format") String format);
}
```

This is my Response java class (POJO or Model class).

```
public class EarthquakeResponse {

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("metadata")
    @Expose
    private Metadata metadata;
    @SerializedName("features")
    @Expose
    private List<Feature> features = null;
    @SerializedName("bbox")
    @Expose
    private List<Double> bbox = null;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Metadata getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    public List<Feature> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(List<Feature> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

    public List<Double> getBbox() {
        return bbox;
    }

    public void setBbox(List<Double> bbox) {
        this.bbox = bbox;
    }

}
```

This is my Feature class (POJO class)

```
public class Feature {

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("properties")
    @Expose
    private Properties properties;
    @SerializedName("geometry")
    @Expose
    private Geometry geometry;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

This is Properties Java class (POJO class). It contains the data I'm interested in. I reduce it to only 3 for checking my code is working or not.

```
public class Properties {

    @SerializedName("mag")
    @Expose
    private Double mag;
    @SerializedName("place")
    @Expose
    private String place;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("detail")
    @Expose
    private String detail;


    public Double getMag() {
        return mag;
    }

    public void setMag(Double mag) {
        this.mag = mag;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

}
```

There are other POJO classes like Geometry, Metadata which are present in JSON response but I'm not interested in it.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for a list of earthquakes -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/earthquake_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my custom adapter layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/earthquake_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/earthquake_mag"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        tools:text="Place"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/earthquake_place"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        tools:text="Place"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/earthquake_url"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        tools:text="Place"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry for my bad English or any improper way of asking a question. I'm new to stackoverflow. I recently sign up.
Please really need some serious help to overcome this.

Comment: if your getting data your activity code should be fine. you should look at your adapter. pls post the same

Comment: When I run the app in emulator sometimes it shows in the verbose sometimes blank white screen. I've added the adapter class above check it please.

Comment: i don't see a problem. you should see the data first. but when you paginate you need to add new items to your list in your adapter and call appropriate notify methods to refresh your list

Comment: One thing that will greatly help, is to modify that **super long** question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Nic3500,sorry about that as it is my first time on stackoverflow to ask a question. I had to ask it as I'm unable to find solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the adapter outside the `Retrofit` method. Something like this:

```
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mItems = new ArrayList<Feature>;
    adapter = new DataAdapter(mItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   // .. other code 

    EarthquakeRequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(EarthquakeRequestInterface.class);
    Call<EarthquakeResponse> responseCall =requestInterface.getJSON("geojson");
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<EarthquakeResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EarthquakeResponse> call, Response<EarthquakeResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                EarthquakeResponse earthquakeResponse = response.body();
                mItems.addAll(earthquakeResponse.getFeatures());
                adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No data Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EarthquakeResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Angelina, it worked now. But can you explain me why it is not working before.?

Comment: @ShubhamVimal adapter is needed to create Views and the list. This should be done when activity is created. You get data by network call, it takes time (from ms to seconds) and then you insert data into the views. It is a common pattern to add data to the adapter, e.g., when you create a new item in the list you want the list to refresh and display this item. `notifyDatasetChanged` method is key here and is very important. You can read more about it online: http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html

Comment: Thanks Angelina. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, now I'm getting new error. 09-20 13:56:52.461 5721-5721/com.example.shubham.retrofittutorial E/Error: timeout